# Flex-lexer how to match simple statements?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am writing flex code to match simple statements of c++. Like:

```
a=b+c;
a=12;
```

etc.

What I have written is:

```
stat ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*+"="([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*|([0-9][^a-zA-Z])+)+(("+"|"-"|"*"|"/")([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*|([0-9][^a-zA-Z])+)+)*+";"$
```

It is accepting statement `c=a+b*23;` `a=2+32;` but not `a=2+3;`.

The above code is: `If a variable name starts from a-zA-Z then accept it, but if it starts with a number then reject this`.

So `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*|([0-9][^a-zA-Z])+)` will match if a word starting with alphabet then there can be digit or alphabet, but if there is a digit then next character should be digit (for statements like `a=10;`).

Comment: The pattern `[^a-zA-Z]` consumes the character matched. Also, though I have reservations about the answer of @JohannesOvermann, he has a point about the even number of digits.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That looks right, but does Flex accept `(?:)`? (Aha. He has removed his comment, but I believe that he was on the right track.)

Comment: The regex was `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*=(?:[0-9]+[-+*|/][0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][-+*|/][a-zA-Z]);$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bg5ifZ/1/) but I am not sure that this will work in Flex. You could try it with the capturing group instead [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhxHYz/1) or if it is not supported then you might use a longer alternation without the `(?:`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vvYsMh/1)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/x8eQOd/2

Comment: You don't. `flex` is a scanner, not s parser. You need a parser for this task. It is far from as simple as you seem to think.

Comment: @user207421 you're right, I just started using flex, so even I don't know the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind a lexical scanner is that it identifies individual tokens (identifiers, literal constants, operators, punctuation, etc.), not complete syntactic constructs like statements.

Trying to use regular expression patterns to recognise something as complex as an expression is almost bound to result in failure, even expressions without parentheses. These can possibly be recognised by a regular expression  but dealing with all the corner cases is going to make the pattern unnecessarily complicated. And once you add parentheses, the task becomes impossible (at least for flex's pattern language, which really is regular unlike most regex libraries).

Instead, use the scanner to split the input into simple pieces (tokens) and discard ignorable sequences (whitespace and constants). The resulting tokens can then be analysed by a context-free parser.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `([0-9][^a-zA-Z])+` only matches numbers with an even number of digits. You probably meant `([0-9][^a-zA-Z]*)+` (inserting a star for the second character class makes it optional).

General note: The regex will accept a superset of that you intend to accept. It is generally impossible to parse nested expressions using regex. You will need a real parser for this.

I would suggest to write a recursive descent parser, for example using a PEG (parser expression grammar). These are quite powerful, yet simple to write and easy  to understand.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar
- https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL

Comment: But why is it working with single before `+` but not after it?

Comment: I mean single digit before `+` is working but not after it. Like a=2+32, have 2 with single digit before `+`. It is accepting it. 2) It is not working.

Comment: This answer is well meant but I am not sure that it is right, unfortunately. Maybe it somehow is right, but it does not look like how I think about regexes, at any rate.

Comment: @PRY: I think this is because the statement `a=2+32` is entirely absorbed by the regex before the `+`.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann If I put `*` then it will accept `a=0b+c` which I don't want.